Related to exporting Fbx animation files from MaxScript in 3ds Max 2022
I found that exporting animations of selected bones in MaxScript is a bit problematic. If this bone does not have a parent bone, it will result in the inability to skip the parent bone and only export the child bone.
my maxscript code:
if exAnimType == 3 then exportFbxSelected = true
local animationDir = skelRolePath + "animation/"
makeDir (animationDir)
exportEchoFile = getSaveFileName caption:"export animation" types:"animation(*.animation)|*.animation" filename:animationDir
if (exportEchoFile == undefined) then return 2
exportFbxPath = (getFilenamePath exportEchoFile) + "/../fbx/"
makeDir exportFbxPath
exportFbxFile = exportFbxPath + (getFilenameFile exportEchoFile) + ".fbx"
FbxExporterSetParam "BakeAnimation"         true    
FbxExporterSetParam "BakeResampleAnimation" true    
exportfile exportFbxFile #noPrompt selectedOnly:exportFbxSelected using:FBXE

I hope to skip unselected parent bones and only export selected child bones
